# Laravel CRON job not working in aws

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, cron, laravel-5.4

I have deployed laravel 5.4 app in AWS Ubuntu 16.04 apache2, i have created task scheduler for sending emails `dailyAt('10:00')`.

When i run the artisan command `php artisan email:reminder` manually every thing works fine.

But when i run `php artisan schedule:run` i am getting `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

I have also ran `* * * * * php /var/www/html/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` referring to documentation.

This is `Kernal.php`

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\EmailReminder::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('email:reminder --force')->dailyAt('10:00');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your crontab has a spelling error: it's `schedule:run`, not `Schedule:run`

Comment: @Darshan Jain the typo is here while writing :)

Answer (score 1):

Your schedule will only work if you call it at 10:00,

add this cronjob

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Laravel will call this function everyminute, and once it is 10:00 it will call the function accordingly.
Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction , search for 'Starting The Scheduler'

Comment: thank you for you response and time, for testing i have changed ti to `->everyFiveMinutes();` and ran the above command still not excecuting

Comment: Try with `->everyMinute();`

Comment: Awesome, we are making progress. i'm getting `Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' email:reminder --force > '/dev/null' 2>&1
` after running `php artisan schedule:run` but not getting any email or SMS

Comment: if i run `php artisan email:reminder` i'm getting email and SMS. what could be the problem here

Comment: hmm, try to `Log` some of your config parameters in the function and check laravel.log, as for the asked question, what do you have in your crontab?

Comment: i ran `corntab -l` it says `no crontab for ubuntu`

Comment: run `crontab -e` and add the line i have in my answer, replace `/path-to-your-project` accordingly ofcourse

Comment: indeed i have replaced the path `* * * * * php /var/www/html/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`, thanks for the command. i'm getting `no crontab for ubuntu - using an empty one`

Comment: if you run `whoami` in terminal what does it return?

Comment: it's returning `ubuntu`

Comment: wow! it worked. the problem was with `--force`. if run `php artisan schedule:run` everything works fine. Ideally it should trigger the `Task` `->everyMinute()` but i'm not getting any emails. you have any idea?

Comment: check your larave.log file under /storage/logs/laravel.log , it might contain usefull information on why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In AWS ECS we can use this without adding cron in to the container

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cronless-schedule

```
php artisan schedule:run-cronless
```